# Is it bad practice?

Tags: php, oop

Is bad practice to do like I show it below? I want to do `next_function_to_do_smth` function if there is rows in certain table and if it is, we call function and use die to close construct. If there isn't, we get rows from other table.

If it is bad practise, what should I use instead of it?

Thank you.

```
class test
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->get_mysql_count("mysql query to get COUNT(*) of smth");

        if($this->get_mysql_count > 0)
        {
            $this->next_function_to_do_smth();
            die();
        }

        $this->get_mysql_count("mysql query to get COUNT(*) of smth2");

        if($this->get_mysql_count > 0)
        {
            $this->next_function_to_do_smth2();
            die();
        }     

        //and so on, and so on   
    }
}
```

Comment: [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This not a very clean solution. I would consider a method initialize() which would be called from the constructor. The method would do the same as your constructor but will 'return' instead of 'die'. Or you could use an `if / else if / else` block to control the program execution flow.

Comment: Great advice with return. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is certainly strange tactics, but I don't think it is directly prohibited somewhere. Only the thing is that a class should not really execute die() construct. May be only very special classes like exception handlers should have this privilege.

May be, if you explain the whole thing, we will find something else to suggest.